# Add Ubuntu to list of Grub boot options

Tags: ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

I have an old laptop with an old version of Debian.  I would like to install Ubuntu as well.  Is it possible to install Ubuntu from the HD (not a rescue CD or flash-drive) and have it reside as a Grub boot option?

Comment: Do you want Ubuntu as an option in the existing grub of Debian? Assuming you want that, do you have an extra partition to store Ubuntu?

Comment: why do not use a liveCD iso install? the the most linux distribution adopt old grub setting you should see this option

Comment: @Yurij73 you probably wanted to include a link for 'this option' but it is not there. (I have seen laptops without CD and fried USB ports, that would work fine otherwise, that is maybe what the OP has at hand.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple choices depending of what you want from Ubuntu:

**Option 1**: Install a Gnome or Unity desktop. This will add only the final desktop view. In that case you do not need a grub option, it's just a desktop option (you can choose your desktop option on the login screen).

**Option 2**: Hard disk partition and system installation. Intended for system uses. Using a LiveCD or other Ubuntu installation disk do a new partition on the HDD and install the Ubuntu distro on the new partition. For this option follow a guide to partition and think a little bit about it.

Think about the option that you want.
Have in mind some things:

- Ubuntu is a verion of Debian, so why to change the base system?
- If you want a beautiful desktop, there are plenty options on the web.
- Partitioning is a little complex at start, but so some paper work and the pieces will fit soon.

Comment: thanks...Option 2 is the way I had envisioned - but instead of from a live-CD doing from the Debian instance in the same way you can install Ubuntu along side an existing Windows install.  But I ended up scrapping what I had and installing the latest version of Debian from scratch. Thanks